# override 'Edit own content' using taxonomy access

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, users

Can I override 'Edit own content' for a particular role and a particular node using taxonomy access? Or better, can I simply switch off Drupal's built-in access content module and solely rely on the settings of TAC (taxonomy access content module)?

What I'm trying to accomplish here is:

a user creates content, the user works on their own content until they think it's ready for moderation upon which they'll set a taxonomy term to 'finished content'. A moderator now comes into play and checks the content of the user. If they decide to approve the content they set a vocabulary term to 'approved content'. This triggers a rule which sets the locking vocabulary of that node to the term 'Locked'. At this point the author should not be able anymore to edit this content.

The problem is that node access permissions still allows the author to edit their own content. How would you tackle such a problem?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a way around it. I'm using the Workbench Access module.

This module, which can be used as a stand alone module, allows you to use taxonomy terms as sections you can set on any node and then you need to assign the roles (or particular users) who can update nodes with these terms/sections. In conjunction with the taxonomy access control module I found that you must at least set the global default for that role to 'view'. If you don't, the users of that particular role won't have update AND view access which is not what I wanted. They can see what they've created but they can't change it anymore after they saved it or after a certain taxonomy term has been set, by themselves or automatically through rules.

Hope that helps others as well!
Cheers!